# How to validate Acrobat fields before page is closed

Tags: validation, field, acrobat

I need to ensure that 2 fields in my pdf are consistent. They get filled in at different times, so I can't use field validation. I need to validate them before the page is closed.

I tried the page/close event but it's too late because the page closes without looking at the rc.

Answer (score 0):

You might use both, the Leave Page event, as well as the Document Will Close event. In both cases, you will have to manually evaluate the field's values, and go back to the page itself.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I'm still having trouble. I can't find the Leave Page event. But more to the point, the Doc Will Close event does not fire when someone is filling the form. There must be a way to perform data validation after the form has been filled in but before exiting. This seems like a pretty common requirement. In my case, I want to ensure that if field A is filled, then field B is also filled. Both are not required fields. In other words, I want to do page validation, not just individual field validation.

Comment: The Leave Page event is a bit hidden, indeed. In the left panel go to the Page thumbnails. Select the page you want to work with. In the context menu, the bottom most entry is Page Properties. In the dialog switch to the Actions tab, select Leave Page in the topmost dropdown… et voilà, there you are…

Comment: In the Leave Page event, you can run any Javascript, which means you can (well, will have to) program your page validation (which may also reach to fields on other pages, if needed).